# How to have a fade out effects using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image]

How to have a fade out effect on JavaScript. As you can see to the image when you click a day it brings down a box and when you click another day the previous box that you click goes up and then there is also a box going down replacing the previous box.

```
function mon() {

    var elem = document.getElementById("box");
    document.getElementById("box").style.background = "#ffba08";
    var pos = 0;
    var id = setInterval(frame, 5);

    function frame() {
        if (pos == 200) {
            clearInterval(id);
        } else {
            pos++
            elem.style.top = pos + "px";
        }
    }
}
```

here is my code for my java that I use for all

Answer (score 0):

```js
function fadeOutEffect() {
  var fadeTarget = document.getElementById("target");
  var fadeEffect = setInterval(function () {
    if (!fadeTarget.style.opacity) {
      fadeTarget.style.opacity = 1;
    }
    if (fadeTarget.style.opacity > 0) {
      fadeTarget.style.opacity -= 0.05;
    } else {
      clearInterval(fadeEffect);
    }
  }, 20);
}

document
  .querySelector("#target")
  .addEventListener("click", fadeOutEffect);
```

```css
#target {
        height: 100px;
        background-color: orangered;
        font-size: 20px;
        color: white;
        transition: background 1s ease-out;
      }
```

```html
<div id="target">Click to fade</div>
```